# Linux sorting awk command

Tags: linux, sorting

I'm new to linux and checking to see if there is any sort command available for below scenario. I have a file containing lines like below.

this is a  10

this is    5

this       40

this is a boy in 3

this is a boy 6

I would like to sort it like

this 40

this is 5

this is a 10

this is a boy 6

this is a boy in 3

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort by the lengths of the lines?

Comment: Jerry yes, by length of the lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about blank lines you can run

```
$ sort <filename>




this 40
this is 5
this is a 10
this is a boy 6
this is a boy in 3
```

[sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_%28Unix%29) can read a file and organize the output.  If you want to remove the empty lines, one option you have is [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)

```
$ sort test.txt | sed '/^$/d'
this 40
this is 5
this is a 10
this is a boy 6
this is a boy in 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of your data is in a text file called `testfile` this answer should work:

```
cat testfile | awk '{ print length, $0 }' | sort -n | cut -d" " -f2-
```

It comes from this question: [Sort a text file by line length including spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917576/sort-a-text-file-by-line-length-including-spaces)

Comment: Should have searched; came up with the exact same solution 2 minutes after you posted. +1 for search-foo

Comment: I want to do this alphabetically - for example                 chilworth 3                                              chilworth and 1                                              chimaeren       1                                               chimaeren is    2

Comment: Jake sorry abt tht. I should have mentioned the word alphabetically by length of lines.

Comment: @Barro if you just want to sort `testfile` alphabetically, then all you need is `sort testfile`