# How to sort by a text file by length of label

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a text file with 559 lines and I only need to sort the labels in a particular part of the file by the longest to the shortest string.  I was thinking to use `sort` but I don't really have a delimiter to use and I am trying to determine the start and end to use flag `-k`.

Here is an example of my text file:

```
^(.*a)$0UMYBPEB(.*)$1$|\0ybpeb\1
^(.*a)$0UMYBPUK(.*)$1$|\0yuk  \1
^(.*a)$0UMYBPUKE(.*)$1$|\0yuke \1
^(.*a)$0USAAHPERD(.*)$1$|\0aahpe\1
^(.*a)$0USAASC(.*)$1$|\0aasc \1
^(.*a)$0USAATF(.*)$1$|\0aatf \1
^(.*a)$0USABARIS(.*)$1$|\0abar \1
^(.*a)$0USABOR(.*)$1$|\0abor \1
^(.*a)$0USACA(.*)$1$|\0aca  \1
^(.*a)$0USACI(.*)$1$|\0aci  \1
^(.*a)$0USACMLA(.*)$1$|\0acmla\1
^(.*a)$0USACSANZ(.*)$1$|\0acsan\1
^(.*a)$0USACTA(.*)$1$|\0acta \1
^(.*a)$0USACTACLASS(.*)$1$|\0cass \1
^(.*a)$0USAD(.*)$1$|\0adbus\1
^(.*a)$0USADAMMATTHEW(.*)$1$|\0adam \1
^(.*a)$0USAEA(.*)$1$|\0aea  \1
^(.*a)$0USAFAS(.*)$1$|\0afas \1
^(.*a)$0USAFRICAN(.*)$1$|\0afric\1
^(.*a)$0USAGI(.*)$1$|\0agi  \1
^(.*a)$0USAGO(.*)$1$|\0ago  \1
```

Notice the labels I am referring to are after the first `$` before `(.*)`

The result I want is the longest to the shortest label:

```
^(.*a)$0USADAMMATTHEW(.*)$1$|\0adam \1
^(.*a)$0USACTACLASS(.*)$1$|\0cass \1
^(.*a)$0USAFRICAN(.*)$1$|\0afric\1
^(.*a)$0USAAHPERD(.*)$1$|\0aahpe\1
^(.*a)$0USACSANZ(.*)$1$|\0acsan\1
^(.*a)$0UMYBPUKE(.*)$1$|\0yuke \1
^(.*a)$0USABARIS(.*)$1$|\0abar \1
^(.*a)$0USACMLA(.*)$1$|\0acmla\1
^(.*a)$0UMYBPEB(.*)$1$|\0ybpeb\1
^(.*a)$0UMYBPUK(.*)$1$|\0yuk  \1
^(.*a)$0USAFAS(.*)$1$|\0afas \1
^(.*a)$0USAASC(.*)$1$|\0aasc \1
^(.*a)$0USAATF(.*)$1$|\0aatf \1
^(.*a)$0USABOR(.*)$1$|\0abor \1
^(.*a)$0USACTA(.*)$1$|\0acta \1
^(.*a)$0USACA(.*)$1$|\0aca  \1
^(.*a)$0USACI(.*)$1$|\0aci  \1
^(.*a)$0USAEA(.*)$1$|\0aea  \1
^(.*a)$0USAGI(.*)$1$|\0agi  \1
^(.*a)$0USAGO(.*)$1$|\0ago  \1
^(.*a)$0USAD(.*)$1$|\0adbus\1
```

Comment: the copy past did not work for me but I think you get the general idea i hope

Comment: If I could get the longest to the shortest line I would be happy

Comment: See: [Sort a text file by line length including spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5917576/3776858)

Comment: @user7011225 Can you give an example of a label?

Answer (score 2):

You can use perl like so.

```
perl -ne 'push @Lines,$_;}{print (sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @Lines)' file
```

Each line is read into array `@Lines`.

`}{` Has a special meaning for end of file.

`sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @Lines` sorts the array using the special variables `$a` and `$b` for the array.

`print` prints the sorted array.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` (and friends) to the rescue

```
awk '{print length($0) "\t" $0}' file | sort -nr | cut -f2-

^(.*a)-bashUSADAMMATTHEW(.*)$|\0adam \1
^(.*a)-bashUSACTACLASS(.*)$|\0cass \1
^(.*a)-bashUSAFRICAN(.*)$|\0afric\1
^(.*a)-bashUSAAHPERD(.*)$|\0aahpe\1
^(.*a)-bashUSACSANZ(.*)$|\0acsan\1
^(.*a)-bashUSABARIS(.*)$|\0abar \1
^(.*a)-bashUMYBPUKE(.*)$|\0yuke \1
^(.*a)-bashUSACMLA(.*)$|\0acmla\1
^(.*a)-bashUMYBPUK(.*)$|\0yuk  \1
^(.*a)-bashUMYBPEB(.*)$|\0ybpeb\1
^(.*a)-bashUSAFAS(.*)$|\0afas \1
^(.*a)-bashUSACTA(.*)$|\0acta \1
^(.*a)-bashUSABOR(.*)$|\0abor \1
^(.*a)-bashUSAATF(.*)$|\0aatf \1
^(.*a)-bashUSAASC(.*)$|\0aasc \1
^(.*a)-bashUSAGO(.*)$|\0ago  \1
^(.*a)-bashUSAGI(.*)$|\0agi  \1
^(.*a)-bashUSAEA(.*)$|\0aea  \1
^(.*a)-bashUSACI(.*)$|\0aci  \1
^(.*a)-bashUSACA(.*)$|\0aca  \1
^(.*a)-bashUSAD(.*)$|\0adbus\1
```

Answer (score 2):

With single ***gawk*** (GNU awk):

```
awk '{a[length,NR]=$0}END{n=asorti(a,dest); for(;n>0;n--) print a[dest[n]]}' file
```

The output:

```
^(.*a)$0USADAMMATTHEW(.*)$1$|\0adam \1
^(.*a)$0USACTACLASS(.*)$1$|\0cass \1
^(.*a)$0USAAHPERD(.*)$1$|\0aahpe\1
^(.*a)$0USAFRICAN(.*)$1$|\0afric\1
^(.*a)$0USABARIS(.*)$1$|\0abar \1
^(.*a)$0UMYBPUKE(.*)$1$|\0yuke \1
^(.*a)$0USACSANZ(.*)$1$|\0acsan\1
^(.*a)$0UMYBPUK(.*)$1$|\0yuk  \1
^(.*a)$0USACMLA(.*)$1$|\0acmla\1
^(.*a)$0UMYBPEB(.*)$1$|\0ybpeb\1
^(.*a)$0USABOR(.*)$1$|\0abor \1
^(.*a)$0USAATF(.*)$1$|\0aatf \1
^(.*a)$0USAASC(.*)$1$|\0aasc \1
^(.*a)$0USAFAS(.*)$1$|\0afas \1
^(.*a)$0USACTA(.*)$1$|\0acta \1
^(.*a)$0USACA(.*)$1$|\0aca  \1
^(.*a)$0USAGO(.*)$1$|\0ago  \1
^(.*a)$0USAGI(.*)$1$|\0agi  \1
^(.*a)$0USAEA(.*)$1$|\0aea  \1
^(.*a)$0USACI(.*)$1$|\0aci  \1
^(.*a)$0USAD(.*)$1$|\0adbus\1
```

---

`length` - length of the line

***asorti(source [, dest [, how ] ])*** - sorts the array indices (in ascending order by default)

`dest` - the result array of sorted indices

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one in GNU awk:

```
$ gawk '
function cmp_val_len(i1,v1,i2,v2) {   # define length comparing function for asort
    return(length(v2) - length(v1)) 
}
{
    a[NR]=$0                          # hash records to a
}
END {
    n=asort(a,b,"cmp_val_len")        # sort the records using defined function
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)                 # loop and
        print b[i]                    # output
}
' file
```

Output (only the start):

```
^(.*a)$0USADAMMATTHEW(.*)$1$|\0adam \1
^(.*a)$0USACTACLASS(.*)$1$|\0cass \1
^(.*a)$0USAAHPERD(.*)$1$|\0aahpe\1
^(.*a)$0USAFRICAN(.*)$1$|\0afric\1
^(.*a)$0UMYBPUKE(.*)$1$|\0yuke \1
....
```

Comment: Nice answer, completely forgot you can define the sort function for asort.

Comment: @123 Me too, took me 15 minutes to remember how it worked again. :D