# How to sort file based on line length including whitespace Perl

Tags: perl, file, sorting

Im trying to sort a file based on line length:

my name is tim
I like pineapples alot
hi

into something like this

hi
my name is tim
i like pineapples alot

I have to include whitespaces in there too, so what i have tried doing is putting each line into an array as one line = 1 string in the array. Then I tried to sort the array but that didnt work out too well.

Comment: Use a string length function for the comparison step of the sort function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917576/sort-a-text-file-by-line-length-including-spaces (there's a perl solution near the bottom)

Comment: @DaveS im confused on this could you go into more detail

Comment: @zzxyz You talking about the one line thing that has perl in it?

Comment: @yibs https://stackoverflow.com/a/46437608/58074 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/40786477/58074 yes

Comment: Yeah, It does what @DaveS  was suggesting.

Comment: @zzxyz im doing an assignment where I have to use a subroutine, i dont think it will count if i do that

Comment: @yibs - Well, there are subroutines.  2 that you've created and are being called by 'the framework', and one that you've both created AND are calling implicitly in the call to `sort`.  But it probably won't count if you have no idea how it works :)

Comment: @zzxyz yea sorry im very new to this. All i was able to do is put each line into an array, so array index 1 would have the first line and so on. Im trying to figure out how to sort it so shortest line is in index 1 and longest is the last , including whitespaces :(

Answer (score 0):

This (from one of the existing "duplicate" answers):

```
perl -ne 'push @a, $_; END{ print sort { length $a <=> length $b } @a }' file
```

And this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
my @arr;

sub compareLength
{
        length $::a <=> length $::b;
}

while (<>)
{
        push @arr, "$_";
}
print (sort {compareLength} @arr);
```

Are basically the exact same thing.  `-n` creates the `while(<>)`, `END` puts stuff after it, and the comparison function is anonymous (vs named) and inline.  (But it still exists and is still a subroutine).

Oh, and I renamed `@a` to `@arr`, because I don't like two different variables both named `a` (`@a` and `$a`)

I hope this helps.

Comment: No need for all that `push`ing ☺ `perl -e 'print sort { length $a <=> length $b } <>' file`

Comment: @haukex - Yeah, I deliberately picked a more....explicit?  solution.  Apparently barely slower, too, which I guess makes sense.