# Absolute path to file as a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a program which is supposed to search through one long string of random digits to find the longest decimal depiction of pi (but no longer than 9). The code is:

```
read -p 'Please specify one: ' fil1
dire=$( locate $fil1 )
if[ <grep -o '314159265' $dire | wc -w> -gt 0 ]
then
echo The longest decimal representation has 9 digits.
return [0]
fi
if[ <grep -o '31415926' $dire | wc -w> -gt 0 ]
then
```

etc.

My error message is `wc: 0] No such file or directory ./pierex.sh: line 7: grep: No such file or directory`and similarly in every line where these commands occur. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Put your code in your question, not a _**picture**_ of your code.

Comment: You need spaces around `[` in `if` statements. And you shouldn't have `<` and `>` around `grep ... | wc -2`, you should have `$(` and `)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lines like:

```
if [<grep -o '31415925' $dir3 | wc -c> -gt 0]
```

should be:

```
if [ $(grep -o '31415925' $dir3 | wc -c) -gt 0 ]
```

The syntax for substituting the output of a command is `$(command)`, not `<command>`. And the `[` command requires a space between the command name and arguments, just like every other command.

BTW, you can do this without repeatedly running `grep`. You can use:

```
match=$(grep -o -E '3(1(4(1(5(9(26?)?)?)?)?)?)?' "$dire")
```

This will return the longest match, then you can just get the length of `$match`. THis assumes that there's only one match in the file; if not, you can sort the results by length and get the longest one. See [Sort a text file by line length including spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917576/sort-a-text-file-by-line-length-including-spaces)

Note also that all these regular expressions will match the digits for π somewhere in the middle of another number, e.g. 42**31314**. To prevent this, you should match a non-digit at the beginning:

```
grep -o -E '(^|[^0-9])31415925'
```

Comment: You might warn that your oneliner only works because the decimals don't have a 3. The same approach for finding `31315` will fail: `echo 3131315 | grep -o -E '3(1(3(1(5?)?)?)?)?'`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped!

Comment: @WalterA The original method also has that problem. The solution is to match a non-digit at the beginning. I've added that to the answer.